# Why is the enclosed area of a voltage-charge Lissajous figure to the dissipated energy per cycle?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, plasma-physics

These Lissajous figures turn up in the study of Dielectric Barrier Discharges driven by AC voltages, but I believe the concept of the "dissipated energy=area enclosed curve" is much more general.

By Stokes' theorem we have for the area $\iint dV dq=\oint V dq$.

In this last path integral, however I wonder whether the voltage/potential V is well-defined: If it is assumed that we are in a quasi-static situation (which is not the case here), this integral should be zero. Otherwise, we need to include the concept of the vector potential (?).

In any case, I don't see what the correct definition of the potential would be here to conclude that the above mentioned integrals equal the dissipated energy.